# how to insert key to an array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

my idea below

```
<?php
$arr=array("dd");
for ($i=0; $i <=4 ; $i++) { 
    $arr[$i];
}
?>
```

it showing an error can any body help me. Any help is appreciable

Comment: what do you try to accomplish?

Comment: i need to create an  array with random number as key

Comment: How many keys do you need?

Comment: Your current array already have a key, say for dd is 0 , if you need anotherkey then u could simply give $arr =array('your_key'=>'your_val')

Comment: `$arr[$i];` doesn't DO anything. it's like having `null;` as a line of code, except it'll also trigger an undefined index warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only refering to the key in the array, you have to set it or read from it.
Because the key does not exist, the only option that remains is to set a value to it.

```
$arr[$i] = 'something';
```

Be careful with setting 'null' to the value. [isset](http://php.net/isset) will return false when a value is null but the key exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
<?php
$arr=array();
for ($i=0; $i <=4 ; $i++) { 
    //$arr[rand(10,100)]=rand(10,1000);
    $arr[$i.'abc']=$i.'abcd';
}
print "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Just remember that if the randomized number is the same for the next loop, it won't generate the expected amount of keys since it'll replace the previous one.

Comment: it's my pleasure @SibyThomas

Answer (score 0):

To insert key to an array:

```
$arr["key"] = "value";
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an array with key and value you should do the following :

```
$array = array();
$array['key'] = 'value';
```

You can also take a look at array_push() that push value at the end of an array

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-push.php